# How to show what engine is being in-used of a table in ClickHouse database?

Tags: clickhouse

Is there any command / SQL that I can show what engine is being in-used of a table in ClickHouse database?

```
create table t (id UInt16, name String) ENGINE = Memory;
insert into t(id, name) values (1, 'abc'), (2, 'xyz');

create table t2 as t ENGINE = TinyLog;
insert into t2(id, name) values (3, 'efg'), (4, 'hij');

create table t3 ENGINE = Log as select * from t;
```

describe command doesn't show the engine information

```
describe t
```

How can I know which engine is in-used?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you run

```sql
SHOW CREATE TABLE t
```

It will give you query to recreate the table `t` with ENGINE info included.

Or run

```sql
SELECT database, name, engine, engine_full
FROM system.tables
```